Is this a theme bug or I should do some css adjustment
This is the first time I use Wordpress theme Classipress.
Two questions:

When I open the Widget customize, the blocks are there, but they are transparent.
When I change the title of a block, the format messed up, and cannot change back.

Please see the gif from my screen.
https://mediumorchid-oyster-970181.hostingersite.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/11/Animation.gif
Are those bugs or I should do some adjustment first.

It sounds like you're experiencing a couple of issues with the ClassiPress theme. Based on what you've described, it could be either a theme bug or something that might need CSS adjustments. Here are a few steps you can try to troubleshoot:

Check for Updates: Ensure that your theme and WordPress are both up to date. Sometimes bugs are fixed in newer versions.

Inspect Element: Use your browser's developer tools to inspect the blocks and see if there are any CSS issues causing the transparency. You might find that adjusting the z-index or other properties could help.

Custom CSS: If the issue persists, you can try adding custom CSS to fix the transparency and formatting issues.


For example:
.wp-block-template-part {
   z-index: 999;
   position: relative;
}

